# Node.js gRPC Connection with tool proto file

Tags: node.js, grpc

I am trying to create a Node.js gRPC connection with a tool I am running on my machine called Pachyderm. I generated a .proto file for the tool, which will simply display the version of the tool. I have generated a server.js for it, however, it is not successfully pulling the tool version by connecting to the respective IP:port of the tool.

If you could help me troubleshoot this, I would greatly appreciate it.

**.proto file**

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package versionpb;
option go_package = "github.com/pachyderm/pachyderm/src/client/version/versionpb";

message Version {
  uint32 major = 1;
  uint32 minor = 2;
  uint32 micro = 3;
  string additional = 4;
}

service API {
  rpc GetVersion(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Version) {}
}
```

**server.js**

```
const path = require('path')

const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader')
const grpc = require('grpc')

const PROTO_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './protos/pach.proto')

const pd = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH)
const hp = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(pd).pach

function sayHello (call, fn) {
  fn(null, { message: 'The tool version is ' + call.request.name })
}

function main () {
  const port = 30650
  const server = new grpc.Server()


  server.bind(`192.161.5.3:${port}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure())
  server.start()
  console.log(`gRPC server started on port: ${port}`)
}

main()
```

Comment: When you run the server, do you get the log line you expect? What is your client code? What failure are you experiencing, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load the package definition and after starting the server you need to add the new service to the server.

```
// method name could be API, api or aPI dependes on how this was generated
server.addService(hp.versionpb.service, {api  : sayHello});
server.start();
```